AppWrite database problems
import Foundation
import Appwrite
import AppwriteModels

let client = Client()
    .setEndpoint("https://-------------------.app/v1")
    .setProject("-------------")
    
let databases = Databases(client)
func prepareDatabase() async -> (Database?, Collection?) {
    let todoDatabase = try? await databases.create(
        databaseId: ID.unique(),
        name: "TodosDB"
    )
    let todoCollection = try? await databases.createCollection(
        databaseId: todoDatabase!.id,
        collectionId: ID.unique(),
        name: "Todos"
    )
    try? await databases.createStringAttribute(
        databaseId: todoDatabase!.id,
        collectionId: todoCollection!.id,
        key: "title",
        size: 255,
        xrequired: true
    )
    try? await databases.createStringAttribute(
        databaseId: todoDatabase!.id as! String,
        collectionId: todoCollection!.id as! String,
        key: "description",
        size: 255,
        xrequired: false,
        xdefault: "This is a test description."
    )
    try? await databases.createBooleanAttribute(
        databaseId: todoDatabase!.id as! String,
        collectionId: todoCollection!.id as! String,
        key: "isComplete",
        xrequired: true
    )
    
    return (todoDatabase, todoCollection)
}

This code is from AppwriteDocs and databases have not all of this functions
I tried everything and nothing works on posting data in the database of my selfhosted AppWrite
It said also when I tried to input JSON as data into a document.
public func addMessage() async throws {

    do {
        let testTodo3: [String: Any] = [
                "title": "Cut the apples",
                "description": "Don't forget to pack them in a box",
                "isComplete": false
            ]
        
       
                
            
    try await databases.createDocument(
            databaseId: "123",
            collectionId: "123",
            documentId: ID.unique(),
            data: testTodo3
        )
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

Here the error was: could not find title (or something like this )

When you say - This code is from AppwriteDocs and databases have not all of this functions, its because these functions are from Server Side SDKs and you don't seem to have that added to your project. You have the Client Side SDK which do not have these methods. There's a difference between the Server & Client Side SDKs. Consult the docs or on discord for further issues.
